# OIDC in combination with LDAP

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, cloud

To authenticate a user we are using siteminder but we want to replace the siteminder with OIDC in cloud environment. For authorization, we are using LDAP. Can we authenticate the user using OIDC and keep LDAP authorization same? The application is in java.